# FullCalendar - How to get clicked location date time when click on event

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullcalendar with react. I want to get the details of the event when point out on the location of the event. I can get event details and calendar details. How to get the point out location date time? Have to get bellow marked place date time,

[image]

Comment: That isn't possible unfortunately. You can detect that the event was clicked on but you can't discover exactly where it was clicked